# How to connect azure virtual machine with log analytics workspace using REST API or Nodejs SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics

**I want to make an automation process where every vm should connect with a log analytics workspace. So can anyone please help me, how do I connect a VM with log analytics workspace via REST API or Nodejs SDK ?**

or

**How do I enable virtual machine Insight through REST API or Nodejs SDK ?**

[image]

Comment: Hi Nancy, thank you so much for your valuable help. Yes I have have implemented the REST API that you maintained, and it's working. 

Now we can enabled the vm insight dynamically, as of now we are using "workspaceKey" statically but for dynamic binding we need to know  "workspaceKey" dynamically.  

So can you please help us, to get the "workspaceKey" using any REST api or nodejs sdk, So that we will dynamically configure the same.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I enable virtual machine Insight through REST API or Nodejs SDK
> ?

You can manage to do it with virtual Machine Extensions to enable the following [agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-enable-overview#agents).

- **Log Analytics agent.** the VM extension for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows) and [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-linux).
- **Dependency agent.** the VM extension for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-dependency-windows) and [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-dependency-linux).

Also, Before a Log Analytics workspace can be used with VM insights, it must have the VMInsights solution installed. Read [Configuring VM insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-overview#configuring-vm-insights).

[image]

For example, I click the green **try it** button in this REST API [Virtual Machine Extensions - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineextensions/createorupdate) and provide my parameters and body to call this API.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/extensions/{vmExtensionName}?api-version=2020-12-01
```

The requests body like this for windows VM will be deployed in order.

Deploy MicrosoftMonitoringAgent

```
{
    "location": "<location>",
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",
        "type": "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": "true",
        "settings": {
            "workspaceId": "<workspaceId>",
            "stopOnMultipleConnections": "true"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "workspaceKey": "<workspaceKey>"
        }
                    }

}
```

Once the above extension is provisioned, you can deploy DependencyAgentWindows.

```
{
    "location": "<location>",
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent",
        "type": "DependencyAgentWindows",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "9.5",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": "true",
        "settings": {
            "workspaceId": "<workspaceId>"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "workspaceKey": "<workspaceKey>"
        }
                    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nancy, thank you so much for your valuable help. Yes I have have implemented the REST API that you maintained, and it's working. Now we can enabled the vm insight dynamically, as of now we are using "workspaceKey" statically but for dynamic binding we need to know "workspaceKey" dynamically. So can you please help us, to get the "workspaceKey" using any REST api or nodejs sdk, So that we will dynamically configure the same.

Comment: You can get the key with [Workspace Shared Keys - Get Shared Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspace%20shared%20keys/getsharedkeys)

Comment: Hi Nancy, thank you for your help. It's working properly, thank you..

Comment: Hi Nancy, With your help of the above solutions, I have enabled the VM Insights. Now I'm facing the below issue. Can you please help me in the below issue:     **[Why log analytics query did not return results where I did integrate the VM with workspace using coding(REST API)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904526/why-log-analytics-query-did-not-return-results-where-i-did-integrate-the-vm-with)**