# Why log analytics query did not return results where I did integrate the VM with workspace using coding(REST API)?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics

**For Windows VM**, If I enabled the **VM Insights** through **Azure portal** and then goto the corresponding log analytics workspace. Within the log analytics workspace, if I run a **vm query** then **LA Query** return the results. Please check the below screenshot:

[image]

**For Windows VM**, If I enabled the **VM Insights** using **coding**(REST API) and then goto the corresponding log analytics workspace. Within the log analytics workspace, if I run a **vm query** then **Log Analytics query** did not return the results. Please check the below screenshot:

[image]

**The above both VM are in the same region and have integrated with the same Log Analytics Workspace.**

**So can anyone please tell me why log analytics query did not return results where I did integrate the VM with workspace using coding(REST API)?**

Comment: Could you please provide the api you use?

Comment: Hi Jim, this is the API details: **[api reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686815/how-to-connect-azure-virtual-machine-with-log-analytics-workspace-using-rest-api/66704648?noredirect=1#comment118101741_66704648)**